# What does it mean? (opencv,python)

Tags: python, opencv

```
gray  =  cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Comment: Please provide more information. What is `frame`? Where is it defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value of frame is None. I am guessing that frame is the image you have read but the path you have defined is wrong hence the error. Check your path and this error should be resolved.